# Unable to invoke internet explorer by using remotewebdriver in c#

Tags: selenium, remotewebdriver

I am able to run my test on a local machine with `IWebDriver` but
unable to run the test on a remote computer with Selenium.

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
capability.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer());
capability.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, new Platform(PlatformType.Windows));
capability.SetCapability("webdriver.ie.driver", @"E:\WebDriver\Browser\");  
string host = "localhost:4444/wd/hub";
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://" + host), capability);
```

The error I am getting is

```
Additional information: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver
  system property; for more information, see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver.
  The latest version can be downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list
```

Comment: Did you do what the error message stated? Set the path to the driver?

Comment: Can you please add the path to above code. I am unable to do that.

Comment: I bet you can google it just as I could, find some potential answers, and try them until you find a solution. If you still can't find a solution, come back and edit your question... tell us what you tried and what the result was.

Comment: I added the new code for path and it did not work

Comment: DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capability.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName,DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer());
            //Path
            capability.SetCapability("webdriver.ie.driver", @"E:\WebDriver\Browser\");
            capability.SetCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
            string host = "localhost:4444/wd/hub";
            RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://" + host), capability);

Comment: Please add your code to your original question so others can more easily see it and it can be properly formatted so it's easier to read.

Comment: DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
capability.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer());
string host = "localhost:4444/wd/hub";RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://" host), capability);

Comment: You are adding comments. I mean click edit and edit the text of your original question (way up top) and add this additional info.

Comment: I have edit the question. Can you please check now.

Comment: Are you still getting the same error with the new code?

Comment: Yeah, I am getting this error even with above code.